# How to cancel individual async computation, being run in parallel with others, from a button click event

Tags: winforms, asynchronous, f#

I've prepared the following WinForms code to be as simple as possible to help answer my question. You can see I have a start button which sets up and runs 3 different async computations in parallel which each do some work and then update labels with a result. I have 3 cancel buttons corresponding to each async computation being run in parallel. How can I wire up these cancel buttons to cancel their corresponding async computations, while allowing the others to continue running in parallel? Thanks!

```
open System.Windows.Forms

type MyForm() as this =
    inherit Form()
    let lbl1 = new Label(AutoSize=true, Text="Press Start")
    let lbl2 = new Label(AutoSize=true, Text="Press Start")
    let lbl3 = new Label(AutoSize=true, Text="Press Start")

    let cancelBtn1 = new Button(AutoSize=true,Enabled=false, Text="Cancel")
    let cancelBtn2 = new Button(AutoSize=true,Enabled=false, Text="Cancel")
    let cancelBtn3 = new Button(AutoSize=true,Enabled=false, Text="Cancel")

    let startBtn = new Button(AutoSize=true,Text="Start")

    let panel = new FlowLayoutPanel(AutoSize=true, Dock=DockStyle.Fill, FlowDirection=FlowDirection.TopDown)
    do
        panel.Controls.AddRange [|startBtn; lbl1; cancelBtn1; lbl2; cancelBtn2; lbl3; cancelBtn3; |]
        this.Controls.Add(panel)

        startBtn.Click.Add <| fun _ ->
            startBtn.Enabled <- false
            [lbl1;lbl2;lbl3] |> List.iter (fun lbl -> lbl.Text <- "Loading...")
            [cancelBtn1;cancelBtn2;cancelBtn3] |> List.iter (fun cancelBtn -> cancelBtn.Enabled <- true)

            let guiContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current

            let work (timeout:int) = //work is not aware it is being run within an async computation
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeout)
                System.DateTime.Now.Ticks |> string

            let asyncUpdate (lbl:Label) (cancelBtn:Button) timeout =
                async {
                    let result = work timeout //"cancelling" means forcibly aborting, since work may be stuck in an infinite loop
                    do! Async.SwitchToContext guiContext
                    cancelBtn.Enabled <- false
                    lbl.Text <- result
                }

            let parallelAsyncUpdates =
                [|asyncUpdate lbl1 cancelBtn1 3000; asyncUpdate lbl2 cancelBtn2 6000; asyncUpdate lbl3 cancelBtn3 9000;|]
                |> Async.Parallel
                |> Async.Ignore

            Async.StartWithContinuations(
                parallelAsyncUpdates,
                (fun _ -> startBtn.Enabled <- true),
                (fun _ -> ()),
                (fun _ -> ()))
```

Comment: Why not set a boolean variable for each task, so that if it is true, that task quits.

Comment: @James Black - if I understand what you are suggestion, I don't think it will achieve quite what I am after: imagining `Thread.Sleep` here is a long running computation which has no idea it is being run from an async computation, I'd like that computation to be forcibly aborted before it completes (indeed, it might be stuck in an infinite loop or something).

Comment: Updated code with function `work` broken out and now containing the `Thread.Sleep` to better illustrate the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancelling threads un-cooperatively is generally a bad practice, so I wouldn't recommend doing that. See for example [this article](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation). It can be done when you're programming with `Thread` directly (using [Thread.Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx)), but none of the modern parallel/asynchronous libraries for .NET (such as TPL or F# Async) use this. If that's really what you need, then you'll have to use threads explicitly.

A better option is to change the `work` function so that it can be cooperatively cancelled. In F#, this really just means wrapping it inside `async` and using `let!` or `do!`, because this automatically inserts support for cancellation. For example:

```
let work (timeout:int) = async {
  do! Async.Sleep(timeout)
  return System.DateTime.Now.Ticks |> string }
```

Without using `async` (e.g. if the function is written in C#), you could pass around a `CancellationToken` value and use it to check if cancellation was requested (by calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequestsd`). Then you can start the three computations using `Async.Start` (creating a new `CancellationTokenSource` for each of the computations).

To do something until they all complete, I would probably create a simple agent (that triggers some event until it receives a specifies number of messages). I don't think there is any more direct way to do that (because `Async.Parallel` uses the same cancellation token for all workflows).

So, I guess that the point of this answer is - if `work` is meant to be cancelled, then it should be aware of the situation, so that it can deal with it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks kindly Tomas, this helps my understanding. I don't quite understand the strategy you are suggesting for cooperative cancellation of the individual async computations being run in parallel, but that's OK because my question really is about uncooperative cancellation (`work` in my real situation is a compiled function I have no control over, so I think I am stuck with `Thread.Abort` or abandoning cancellation altogether).

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, I was expecting that you're probably running something that cannot be cooperatively cancel (so I didn't explain the strategy for cooperative case very well...). I'm afraid `Thread.Abort` is the only option then - though it can be probably wrapped in some nice `async`.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomas mentioned, forcibly stopping a thread is a bad idea, and designing something that doesn't realize it is a thread to be able to stop raises flags, in my mind, but, if you are doing a long calculation, if you are using some data structure, such as a 2 or 3D array, then one option would be to be able to set that to `null`, but, this violates many concepts of F#, since what your function is working on should be not only immutable, but if there is some array that is going to be changed, then nothing else should be changing it.

For example, if you need to stop a thread that is processing a file (I had to do this before), then, since the file couldn't be deleted, as it was open, then I was able to open it in Notepad, then just delete all the content, and save it, and the thread crashed.

So, you may want to do something like this in order to accomplish your goal, but, I would suggest that you re-evaluate your design and see if there is a better way to do this.